# Why am I not getting all cassandra metrics in grafana?

Tags: cassandra, grafana, telegraf, jolokia, grafana-alerts

We are using Apache Cassandra(not datastax version) db. And for monitoring purpose , we are using jolokia's REST APIs to retrieve cassandra metrics.

All the jolokia APIs are working fine, means I can get all the metrics by using jolokia's rest APIs. We are also using telegraf, telegraf collects the metrics from jolokia and forwards them into InfluxDB.

But when I add influxdb connection in grafana with 'telegraf' db then grafana is not showing me all the metrics(showing only 5-6 metrics).

I am able to call all the jolokia APIs through rest client which returns JSON response of cassandra metrics but through grafana I can see only few metrics.

What changes I need to make in telegraf's config to get all the metrics in grafana? 
And I also need to set alerts like if per second write rate in cassandra exceeds to 1k then it should notify me through mail. So how can I do this ?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [this post](https://andreastech.wordpress.com/2018/07/20/cassandra-performance-monitoring-part-3-what-to-monitor/)  on how to setup a simple Cassandra dashboard. It might help.

All metrics you would like to record needs to be defined in the telegraf.conf in the `[[input.cassandra]]` section˙, e.g:

> ```
>   [[inputs.cassandra]] 
>     context = "/jolokia/read" 
>     servers = [":8778"]
>     metrics = [ 
>         "/java.lang:type=Memory/HeapMemoryUsage",
>         "/java.lang:type=Memory/NonHeapMemoryUsage",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Storage,name=Load",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Storage,name=TotalHintsInProgress",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Storage,name=Exceptions",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,name=Latency,scope=*",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Client,name=connectedNativeClients",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=CommitLog,name=PendingTasks",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=CommitLog,name=TotalCommitLogSize",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,name=Timeouts,scope=*",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Compaction,name=BytesCompacted",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,name=WriteLatency",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,name=ReadLatency",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,name=RangeLatency",
>         "/org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ColumnFamily,scope=*,name=AllMemtablesLiveDataSize,keyspace=*" 
> ]
> ```

As for your second question:

- define a panel for displaying information regarding the data (I am not sure, what do you mean by write rate in this case)
- go to the Alert tab in the Alert config section and define your condition when the alert supposed to trigger
- go to the Alert tab Notification section and add your email address and message.